# Cannot retrive picklist values in LWC ERROR: Error during LWC component connect phase: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')]

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, error, bug

```
// Object = Free_Budget__c
// Picklist = Reason__c


import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import Reason from '@salesforce/schema/Free_Budget__c.Reason__c';

export default class MultipleAccountInsertion extends LightningElement {

    @track pickListValues;
    @track error;
    @track values;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
            recordTypeId: "$getObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
            fieldApiName: Reason
        })
        reasonValues;

        wiredPicklistValue({ data, error}){
            if(data){
                console.log(`Picklist values are ${data}`);
                this.pickListValues = data.values;
                this.error= undefined;
            }
            if(error){
                console.log(`Error while fetching Picklist values ${error}`);
                this.error = error;
                this.pickListValues = undefined;
            }
        }
```

---

```
<template>

            <template for:each={freeBudgetRecList} for:item="Free_Budget__c" for:index="index">
                <tr key={keyIndex}>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                            {index}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-m-top_large">
                            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Free_Budget__c" id={index} >
                                <lightning-input-field field-name="Account__c" variant="label-hidden" access-key={index} onchange={changeHandler} value={Free_Budget__c.Account__c} required> </lightning-input-field>
                            </lightning-record-edit-form>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <lightning-input name="fbAmount" access-key={index} id={index} type="Currency" onchange={changeHandler} value={Free_Budget__c.Amount__c} required>
                        </lightning-input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <lightning-input name="fbEffectiveDate" access-key={index} id={index} type="Date" onchange={changeHandler} >
                        </lightning-input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <lightning-input name="fbReason" access-key={index} id={index} type="Text" onchange={changeHandler} value={Free_Budget__c.Reason__c}>
                        </lightning-input>
                    </td>  
                    <td>
                        **<lightning-combobox name="level"
                          label="Level"
                          value={value}
                           placeholder="-Select-"
                           options={reasonValues.data.values}
                    >
                        </lightning-combobox>**  
                    </td>           
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="action:delete" access-key={index} id={index} alternative-text="Click to Call" size="small" title="large size" onclick={removeRow}>
                            </lightning-icon>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                
                </tr>
                
            </template>
        
        </table>
    </lightning-card>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

your template is rendered before the wire could retrieve the picklist values, thus `reasonValues.data` is undefined and trying to render `reasonValues.data.values` gives an error. You can prevent this by making sure the combobox doesn't render before the values are available using `<template if:true={resonValues.data}>`

Answer (score 1):

As wire are asynchronous, I think LWC tries to render your template before the wire result is returned.

This means that at first reasonValues may not yet be populated. Try to add a rendering condition in your template to only render your combobox when the wire has returned results:

```
<template if:true={reasonValues.data}>
    <lightning-combobox name="level"
        label="Level"
        value={value}
        placeholder="-Select-"
        options={reasonValues.data.values}>
    </lightning-combobox>
</template>
```